# unique values of rows

Tags: r, experimental-design

I often encounter data that looks like this:

```
#create dummy data frame
data <- as.data.frame(diag(4))
data[data==0] <- NA
data[2,2] <- NA
data

#V1 V2 V3 V4
#1  1 NA NA NA
#2 NA NA NA NA
#3 NA NA  1 NA
#4 NA NA NA  1
```

Rows represent participants and columns V1 through V4 represent the condition that the participant is in (e.g., a 1 under V1 means this participant is in condition 1, a 1 under V4 means this participant is in condition 4). Sidenote: The data are not symmetric, so there are a lot more participants spread over the 4 conditions.

What I want is a vector with the condition for each participant:

```
1 NA  3  4
```

I wrote the following bit, but was wondering if there was a more efficient way (i.e., using fewer lines of code)?

```
#replace entries with condition numbers 
cond <- data + matrix(rep(0:3, 4), 4, byrow=TRUE) #add 0 to 1 for condition 1...

#get all unique elements (ignore NAs)
cond <- apply(cond, 1, function(x)unique(x[!is.na(x)]))

#because I ignored NAs just now, cond[2,2] is numeric(0)
#assign NA to all values that are numeric(0)
cond[sapply(cond, function(x) length(x)==0)] <- NA

cond <- unlist(cond)
cond
#[1]  1 NA  3  4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `max.col` with `ties.method='first'` on the logical matrix of non-NA elements in 'data'.  To make the rows that have only NA elements as NA, we multiply the `max.col` index with `rowSums` of logical matrix with 0 non-NA rows converted to NA (`NA^`).

```
 max.col(!is.na(data), 'first')* NA^!rowSums(!is.na(data))
 #[1]  1 NA  3  4
```

Or another option is `pmax`.  We multiply the column index with the data so that the non-NA elements get replaced by the index.  Then, use `pmax` with `na.rm=TRUE` and get the max value per each row.

```
 do.call(pmax, c(col(data)*data, na.rm=TRUE))
 #[1]  1 NA  3  4
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `reshape2` package:

```
> data$ID <- rownames(data)
> melt(data, 'ID', na.rm=TRUE)
   ID variable value
1   1       V1     1
11  3       V3     1
16  4       V4     1
```

IMHO, this has the advantage of keeping the ID variable along with the treatment factor; also if you have a response measurement it comes along too in the value column.

EDIT:

If you want to include the subject under no conditions, you can reconstruct that indicator variable explicitly:

```
data$VNA <- ifelse(apply(is.na(data), 1, all), 1, NA)
```

Answer (score 1):

Less clever and efficient than other solutions, but perhaps more readable?

```
apply(data,
      MARGIN = 1, 
      FUN = function(x) { 
          if(all(is.na(x))) return(NA)
          return(which(!is.na(x)))
      }
)
# [1]  1 NA  3  4
```