# sieve out non-NA entries from data frame while retaining rows with only NA

Tags: r, dataframe, qualtrics

I am looking for a more efficient way (in terms of length of code) of converting a `data.frame` from:

```
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
# 1  1  2  3 NA NA NA NA NA NA
# 2 NA NA NA  3  2  1 NA NA NA
# 3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
# 4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
# 5 NA NA NA NA NA NA 1  2  3
```

to

```
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]    3    2    1
#[3,]   NA   NA   NA
#[4,]   NA   NA   NA
#[5,]    1    2    3
```

That is, I want to remove excess NAs but correctly represent rows with only NAs.

I wrote the following function which does the job, but I am sure there is a less lengthy way of achieving the same.

```
#Dummy data.frame
data <- matrix(c(1:3, rep(NA, 6), 
          rep(NA, 3), 3:1, rep(NA, 3), 
          rep(NA, 9),
          rep(NA, 9),
          rep(NA, 6), 1:3),
          byrow=TRUE, ncol=9)
data <- as.data.frame(data)

sieve <- function(data) {

        #get a list of all entries that are not NA
        cond <- apply(data, 1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
        #set integer(0) equal to NA
        cond[sapply(cond, function(x) length(x)==0)] <- NA

        #check how many items there are in non-empty rows
        #(rows are either empty or contain the same number of items)
        n <- max(sapply(cond, length))

        #replace single NA with n NAs, where n = number of items
        #first get an index of entries with single NAs
        index <- (1:length(cond)) [sapply(cond, function(x) length(x)==1)]
        #then replace each entry with n NAs
        for (i in index) cond[[i]]  <- rep(NA, n)

        #turn list into a data.frame
        cond <- matrix(unlist(cond), nrow=length(cond), byrow=TRUE)
        cond
}

sieve(data)
```

My question resembles [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35158914/4798582) about extracting conditions to which participants are assigned (for which I received great answers). I tried expanding these answers to the current dummy data, but without success so far. Hence my rather lengthy custom function.

---

Edit: Additional info for why I am asking this question: The first data frame represents the raw output from an experiment in which I assigned participants to one of three conditions (using 3 here for simplicity). In each condition, participants read a different scenario, but then answered the same set of questions about the scenario they had read. Qualtrics recorded answers from participants in the first condition in the columns `V1`through `V3`, answers from participants in the second condition in the columns `V4`through `V6` and answers from participants in the third condition in columns `V7`through `V9`. (If this block of questions would have contained 4 questions it would have been columns `V1` through `V4` for answers from participants in the first condition, `V2` through `V8` for answers from participants in the second condition ...).

---

Comment: Could you explain why your data currently uses different variables (columns) for data that you want to collapse into the same variables?

Comment: Do you always have non-NA elements with length same except the one with all NA rows?

Comment: @MekkiMacAulay it's because of counterbalancing, I'll explain this in more detail in an edit. @akrun yes, the length of non-NA elements is always the same, although I don't know it  in advance, which is why I added the `n <- max(sapply(cond, length))` bit.

Comment: Do you require the NA rows to be intact?

Comment: @Brandon, yes, the rows with only NA should also be represented as rows of only NA in the new data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this if the length of non-NAs is always the same in rows that aren't entirely filled with NA:

First, create a data frame with the appropriate (transposed) dimensions, and fill it with NAs.

```
d2 <- data.frame(
        matrix(nrow = max(apply(d, 1, function(ii) sum(!is.na(ii)))),
               ncol=nrow(d)))
```

Then, using `apply` fill that data frame, then transpose it to get your desired outcome:

```
d2[] <- apply(d, 1, function(ii) ii[!is.na(ii)])
t(d2)
#   [,1] [,2] [,3]
#X1    1    2    3
#X2    3    2    1
#X3   NA   NA   NA
#X4   NA   NA   NA
#X5    1    2    3
```